# How automatically add 1 year date to an existing date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a task to automatically bill all registered patients in `PatientsInfo` table an Annual Bill of N2,500 base on the `DateCreated` column.

Certainly I will use a stored procedure to insert these records into the `PatientDebit` table and create a SQL Job to perform this procedure.

How will I `select *` patients in `PatientsInfo` table where `DateCreated` is now 1 yr old for me to insert into another table `PatientDebit`.

I have my algorithm like this:

1. select date of registration for patients from `PatientsInfo` table
2. Add 1 year to their `DateCreated`
3. Is date added today? if yes,
4. Insert record into `PatientDebit` table with the bill of N2,500
5. If no, do nothing.

Please how do I write the script?

Comment: How is this related to C#? (Edit: removed tag)

Comment: Or google "datediff" if you want the time span between 2 dates.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you even have a working query that gets the records that are older then 1 year?  When you have this come back and we can help you.

Comment: Your logic is backward. You should select only those patients from PatientInfo whose DateCreated matches (Today - 1 year). This means you are only processing those patients you know match your condition. As far as figuring out the date, as others have said you should use `DateAdd`. The documentation is quite good.

Answer (score 16):

Use DATEADD, i.e.:

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, '2006-08-30')
```

Ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the columns of the 2 tables are the same:

```
INSERT INTO PatientDebit
SELECT * from PatientsInfo WHERE DateCreated<DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Make sure you have an index on `DateCreated` if `PatientsInfo` has a lot of records as it could potentially be slow otherwise

Comment: Glad it did! Maybe you could consider accepting the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

there should be .add or addyear() function in sql. You add like .add(year, day, month). Read upon sql datetime add year, month and seconds. It is pretty straightforward. It is just like c#.

Dateadd(info). now time is. getdate().